# Cosa significa "sbirellata" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella introduzione al racconto *Grammelot di Scapino* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Ricorderete senz’altro il costume del Re 
>   Sole: un lungo sbuffo sulle maniche, trine
>   finemente ricamate sul petto e intorno al 
>   collo montanti fino alle orecchie e dietro la nuca... un prurito da impazzire! Il che causava il classico scatto di testa del sovrano del tutto simile alla **sbirellata** di collo di uno stallone.

Ricercando nei dizionari non ho trovato "sbirellata", ho trovato soltanto "[sbiellare](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=sbiellare)" con questo significato

> **3.** (scherz.) perdere il controllo dei nervi; uscire di testa, dare i numeri

che non so se abbia qualcosa a che vedere. La mia domanda è: sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "sbirellata" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Comment: Probabilmente si tratti di un [termine di uso regionale](https://books.google.es/books?id=g_fAAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=sbirellare&source=bl&ots=dWfqvy6KZS&sig=FCI9c-w54zBMrWc_eVc0i9m-emo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-hdecotLYAhXKshQKHQt5DhwQ6AEIDTAA#v=onepage&q=sbirellare&f=false).

Comment: L’ho trovato anche in un dizionario del cornetano (dialetto tarquiniese): http://www.iltarquiniese.it/words/define/term/Sbirellàre+%28v%29/word_id/1067#comments

Comment: @Benedetta: Appare anche [birellata](http://www.iltarquiniese.it/words/define/term/Birellata+%28s%29) come "bastonata, tortorata (colpo di birello)".

Comment: @Benedetta: Si trova anche [qui](http://www.artestoriatarquinia.it/1983_Bollettino/B.B.%20_IL%20DIALETTO%20CORNETANO.pdf).

Comment: @Charo: Bruno Blasi è proprio il compilatore del dizionario che ho linkato.

Answer (score 1):

Dato il passaggio sarei propenso a inferire che una "sbirellata" sia lo scatto di testa tipico che fa uno stallone quando percepisce di non essere cavalcato bene, o quando lo si forza a fare cose che non vorrebbe.